# PHP strpos with special characters

Tags: php, special-characters, strpos

i try to check a string with strpos().

```
$a = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This works just fine

```
if (strpos($a, 'en' ) == true)
```

But this doesn't

```
if (strpos($a, '/en/' ) == true) - Doesn't work
```

I tried a lot of things to escape the character or format the string but as it seems I am too stupid...

Comment: What is in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ?

Comment: how it doesn't work ? if statement not passing ?

Comment: It contains the string of a homepage after "http://www.tld.de/"

Comment: _It contains the string of a homepage after.._ I know that! But what is in YOUR `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ?

Comment: /en/  for example. I want to check which language is set at the viewed site

Comment: "how it doesn't work ? if statement not passing ?"  if i check for "en" it delivers true. If I check for "/en/" it delivers false.

Comment: You can use `strstr()`as well

Comment: `strpos() == true` does not make sense since it returns an **index**: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php; you could use `!== FALSE` instead

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `strpos` returns the position or FALSE if not found.

So if the url is `/en/something/some` then you are hitting the situation where en is a position 1 and any non-zero number is true

When you do `/en/` then the starting position is 0 and that is false.

you need to check with `===` in the end or more accurately `!==` example

```
<?php

$a= "/en/blo";

if (strpos($a, '/en/' ) !== false){
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

Comment: That's it. Working perfectly. Can't tell you how thankful I am for your solution as also for the explanation.

Comment: How about url like this `/jp/home/en/content`, it will TRUE also..

Comment: @MochamadArifin yeah he is just looking for `\en\` as far as I can tell. The only issue is when it is at the beginning cause 0 = false. If you want to check the first 4 are `/en/` I would just substr and verify or just straight up make sure strpos for `/en/` is 0.

Comment: @LukasHwm glad to help. Not sure if you can but accepting the answer is always appreciated!